# Create default billing/shipping address

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.1

I need to create default billing address for new user.
To create billing/shipping address I'm using the next code:

```
protected function createAddress($isDefaultBilling = false, $isDefaultShipping = false) {

        $address = $this->addressFactory->create()
            ->setCustomerId($this->customerObject->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultBilling($isDefaultBilling)
            ->setIsDefaultShipping($isDefaultShipping)
            ->setCity('n/a')
            ->setCountryId('UA')
            ->setCompany('n/a')
            ->setFax('n/a')
            ->setFirstname($this->customerObject->getFirstname())
            ->setLastname($this->customerObject->getLastname())
            ->setPostcode('n/a')
            ->setStreet(['n/a'])
            ->setTelephone('n/a');

            return $this->addressRepository->save($address);
            // die('testing'); // wut???
            // return $address;

    }
```

`$this->addressFactory` is an instance of `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory`

and `$this->addressRepository` is `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`

The code looks properly, and in var/debug/db.log I see the query:

```
## 2016-10-14 10:52:27
## 2909 ## QUERY
SQL: INSERT INTO `mg_customer_address_entity` (`parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `city`, `company`, `country_id`, `fax`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `postcode`, `street`, `telephone`) VALUES (?, '2016-10-14 10:52:27', '2016-10-14 10:52:27', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
BIND: array (
  0 => 12,
  1 => 'n/a',
  2 => 'n/a',
  3 => 'UA',
  4 => 'n/a',
  5 => 'fname',
  6 => 'lname',
  7 => 'n/a',
  8 => 'n/a',
  9 => 'n/a',
)
AFF: 1
TIME: 0.0015
```

BUT there is NO data in database!

For debug, I saw in /home/serf/www/magento/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php, and in function `save` the call `$this->isModified($object)` returns false.

I tried to use \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory:

```
$model = $this->addressModelFactory->create();
$model->setDataChanges(true);
$address = $model->getDataModel()
    ->.....
```

But the result was not changed.
And, finally, I tried `$model->getResource()->save($model)`. And got an error like "City is required field".

I tried more ways, but each time the behaviour is different: it may assign new ID to billing/shipping (but the data was not saved in database!), or die with message like "No such entity with addressId = 122", when I try to edit the new billing.

In the last I've uncommented the string `die('testing');`, and the address was created. Even if I don't change the billing after creating, it appears in database only if `die(..)` is uncommented.
So, what am I doing wrong?

UPD. How am I using the code:

```
$this->defaultBilling = $this->createAddress(true, false);
$this->customerObject->setDefaultBilling($this->defaultBilling->getId());
$this->customerRepository->save($this->customerObject);
```

where `$this->customerObject` is instance of `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface`, and `$this->customerRepository` -- `Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving customer is not required. On string `$this->customerRepository->save($this->customerObject);` the transaction (where billing is saving to database) was rolled back.